# Program does not return output for large value of input such as 50.It returns 0.this is a factorial program using recursion

Tags: c

```
/*Program to find factorial of a number using recursion*/ 

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
/*Function to recursively compute factorial of a number*/
long int fact(long int n)
{
    if(n==0)
    return 1;
    return n*fact(n-1);
}
int main()
{
    long  int n;
    printf(" enter n ");
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    printf ("%ld",fact(n));  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `long int` would be able to hold value of factorial of `50`.  You need to use array or pointer instead of primitive data types .

Comment: So is it possible to change the default stack value

Comment: So tats an overflow yano

Comment: 50! = 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000 doesn't fit `long int`.

Comment: The largest factorial that can be stored in a 64-bit int is 20!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`50!` is a very large number (over 60 digits) and `2^64` is less than `50!`. The reason that you don't get the right number is that you get [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), you are counting above the limit of what your computer can calculate.

```
enter n 50
-3258495067890909184
```

If you have a 64-bit integer, the largest value it can represent is 2^64 which I is smaller than 50!. Therefore you get overflow.

Normally in these situations you resort to some trick, similar to a 4-bit system running 8-bit code by doubling the number of instructions per word (the way [Intels first CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004) had 8-bit code).

So your 64-bit system actually can handle 128-bit words, you just have to write an algorithm that puts the data in "chunks" so that you can double your word length.

Comment: BTW, 128-bit words are insufficient for `50!`.  Need 215+

Answer (score 1):

`50!` is `30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000` or about `3.04e+64`, a 215-bit number.   This value typically exceeds the range of types such as `long`.  Even `uintmax_t` and `unsigned long long` need only to needs to be able to represent at least 64-bit integers.

```
long int fact(long int n) {
  ...
  // Overflows!
  return n*fact(n-1);
```

To get an exact answer, code could use alternate types.  The following uses a string/decimal representation of a integer.  It works for large values of `n` as correct functionality being limited by the buffer size.

```
char *strfact_mult(char *s, unsigned x) {
  unsigned sum = 0;
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  size_t i = len;
  while (i > 0) {
    sum += (s[--i] - '0')*x;
    s[i] = sum%10 + '0';
    sum /= 10;
  }
  while (sum) {
    len++;
    memmove(&s[1], s, len);
    s[i] = sum%10 + '0';
    sum /= 10;
  }
  return s;
}

char *str_fact(char *dest, unsigned n) {
  strcpy(dest, "1");
  while (n > 1) {
    strfact_mult(dest, n--);
  }
  return dest;
}

int main(void) {
  char buf[1000];
  puts(str_fact(buf, 0));
  puts(str_fact(buf, 1));
  puts(str_fact(buf, 5));
  puts(str_fact(buf, 50));
}
```

Output

```
1
1
120
30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000
```

Comment: @ringzero Sure, join the party.

Answer (score 0):

It will not go with standard C types, you need something else(maybe string) . Please look at http://onlinemschool.com/math/formula/factorial_table/

As you can see, it is quite big number.